# Lyx: add "copy", "paste" and "cut" to the right click menu for selection

Tags: lyx

I'm using Lyx 2.3.3. There are "copy", "paste" and "cut" options in the right click menu for selections of texts and the whole math equations. But there are no such options for selections of part of math. Yes, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V and Ctrl + X work. But they are very inconvenient as one has to switch between mouse and keyboard several times. I wonder if it is possible to add such options to the right click menu.

Comment: Good points. I don't think there is a way (but I'm not sure). You might want to make a bug report at https://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: Tip: Use the keyboard shortcuts whenever possible. Leave the mouse to the cats as far as possible. The carpal tunnel syndrome is not fun.

Comment: @Glenn I suggest you answer your question (it's actually encouraged for you to answer your own question). You can just say "no, not currently possible. Here is the bug report: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11799". By having an accepted answer in a question, it is easier to find questions that still need answers. By the way, thanks for opening that bug report!

Comment: @scottkosty, Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by the Lyx team! The solution:

Add these context-menus in your local installation of LyX by adding the following code to the `Menu "context-math"` section in the `stdcontext.inc` file in the LyX's library directory or a custom copy of the file in your user directory (you can see the paths of these directories in About LyX dialog).

```
Item "Cut" "cut"
Item "Copy" "copy"
Item "Paste" "paste"
Submenu "Paste Recent|e" "edit_pasterecent"
Separator
```

Ref: the bug report: [lyx.org/trac/ticket/11799](https://lyx.org/trac/ticket/11799).

Comment: Note that the enhancement has already been accepted and fixed. It will be in LyX 2.3.5, whenever that is released (probably not for a while since 2.3.4 was released not too long ago).